# postgres: select rows where a parameter is anything

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

i am passing parameters in a query in the WHERE clause. I would like to create a case where any param in the where is fine (like obmitting the value).

for example:

`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE lang=%s`

i can pass in the placeholder strings like 'en', 'it', 'es'. but what about if i want to take everything in the lang column? like if i didn't mention the lang in the where clause?

is there something like:

`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE lang=ANYTHING`

??

Comment: Something similar to: WHERE lang=%s OR %s IS NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NULL` as an indicator you don't care about the language. Then you can use `IS NULL` to check if the value is null and therefore include all rows. Use `OR` to append the equality check. Like that, if the value isn't null, it must match the language for a row to be returned.

```
SELECT *
       FROM users
       WHERE %s IS NULL
              OR lang = %s;
```

Comment: thank you. and i pass always the same value to both those palceholders right?

Comment: @91DarioDev: Yes.